# For loop stuck on first iteration, and others don't return correctly

Tags: python, list

I am stuck.

I'm trying to convert user input of 9 letters and convert them to numbers coinciding with the numbers 0-9 (like a phone).

So far, my letters list object works, but when it gets to the for loop in the 'letter_converter' function, it will only return ['2','2'...] and won't continue through the entirety of the loop, for any other letter from the 'letters' list, the number won't return anything other than the '2', and for all else: it returns 'None'.

Can someone help me with why this is? I'm more looking for the logic behind the answer because I am brand new to coding.

```
def phone_number_converter():

    '''This program will take user input to convert nine letters
    to a phone number using the text numbers from a phone number'''

    def letter_list():
        #takes 9 character string of user input and adds them to a list
        #returns: list object 'letters'
        word_input = input('Input nine letters: ')
        word = word_input
        letters = []
        for letter in word:
            letters.append(letter)
        return letters

    def letter_converter(letters):
        #takes a list object with separate strings and converts them to '0 - 9'
        #returns:list object called 'numbers'
        n = len(letters)
        numbers = []
        
        for letter in letters:
            while (len(numbers)) < n:
                if letter == 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
                    numbers.append('2')
                elif letter == 'd' or 'e' or 'f':
                    numbers.append('3')
                elif letter == 'g' or 'h' or 'i':
                    numbers.append('4')
                elif letter == 'j' or 'k' or 'l':
                    numbers.append('5')
                elif letter == 'm' or 'n' or 'o':
                    numbers.append('6')
                elif letter == 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's':
                    numbers.append('7')
                elif letter == 't' or 'u' or 'v':
                    numbers.append('8')
                else:
                    numbers.append('9')    
        return numbers
    letters = letter_list()
    numbers = letter_converter(letters)
    return numbers 
print(phone_number_converter())}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-single-value)

Comment: The `while` loop keeps iterating with the same letter until the number length is 9. On subsequent iterations of the `for` loop the number length is already 9 so the `while` loop doesn't even start. Just remove the inner `while`

Comment: That's in addition to needing to fix the `if` condition as explained in an answer below

Comment: Why not use a dictionary instead of the numerous 'elifs'.

Comment: `elif`s are a good approach in this case. I would keep them

Comment: @Stuart I only added the while loop as an attempt to make my loop work

Answer (score 2):

```
    while (len(numbers)) < n:
        if letter == 'a' or 'b' or 'c':
            numbers.append('2')
        elif letter == 'd' or 'e' or 'f':
            numbers.append('3')
        elif letter == 'g' or 'h' or 'i':
            numbers.append('4')
        elif letter == 'j' or 'k' or 'l':
            numbers.append('5')
        elif letter == 'm' or 'n' or 'o':
            numbers.append('6')
        elif letter == 'p' or 'q' or 'r' or 's':
            numbers.append('7')
        elif letter == 't' or 'u' or 'v':
            numbers.append('8')
        else:
            numbers.append('9')
```

Here you compare “b” or “c” and in if it will return always true, so you need to do this with each if

```
    if letter in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
```

Comment: **Note: The difference is that 
`if letter == 'a' or 'b' or 'c':` doesn't exactly read directly as english.**

It should actually be read as
`if (letter == 'a') or ('b') or ('c'):`
And could be seen as each condition that isn't already of type bool has [`bool()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=bool#bool) being called on it. 

So it's something like 
`if (letter == 'a') or bool('b') or bool('c'):`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this more easily by making a function that converts a single letter to a digit and then using a list comprehension to apply that to the input word.

```
def letter_to_phone_digit(letter):
    groups = ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz"]
    for digit, letters in enumerate(groups, start=2):
        if letter in letters:
            return digit

def phone_number_converter():
    word_input = input('Input nine letters: ')
    return [letter_to_phone_digit(letter) for letter in word_input]
```